# Is there any program or website that allows me to create phylogenetic trees without having to insert an already created dataset?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, database, software

[I asked a similar question on Quora before](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-program-or-website-that-can-allow-me-to-quickly-create-phylogenetic-trees), but did not get any useful answers as the program the one answerer suggested turned out to have the exact same problems as all others I have found so far.

Most programs for the construction of phylogenetic trees—being made for researchers in various biological disciplines—seem to rely on the input of a dataset that is a formulation of collected genetic and/or anatomical data.

Specifically, I am looking for a program that is like [this](https://labs.minutelabs.io/Tree-of-Life-Explorer/#/), but with a GUI that allows tree editing (i.e. you can add and remove new taxa), for example, poorly described/novel theoretical species, dubious species, and subspecies and can be used to create simplified versions of charts like [these](https://sta.sh/21osfp0f249m).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Note in particular that this doesn't appear to be a question that is appropriate for this forum — a tree without data is fiction not biology. ——— There is a [worldbuilding.se], perhaps that might be an appropriate venue for this question? Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome The reason why I first asked this question on here, rather than the Worldbuilding forum was because I was not sure that anyone on there would have the expertise to answer the question, given the fact that the majority of questions deal with fantasy and (relatively) soft sci-fi concepts, and when hard scientific concepts are brought up, they are not usually in the the fields I am looking for.

Comment: @tyersome So, do you think I should still try to ask the question there? Also, now that I look back upon it, I feel that a better way of phrasing the question would be that I am looking for a software where you can **directly** create and edit phylogenetic trees (through an intuitive graphical interface), rather than having to _indirectly_ edit it through the difficult and gratuitous creation and/or modification of a dataset that one must run through the program.

Comment: I can't tell you whether Worldbuilding is the right place, but I can assure you that your question doesn't belong here and won't get an answer even if it isn't closed. The problem is that an expert in phylogenetics is unlikely to have an answer because no one studying biology would need to build a tree that wasn't based on data. Consequently, I doubt that anyone has taken the time to create software for that purpose.

Comment: I agree it does not belong here but I don't understand why you can't use some general graphics program like inkscape or photoshop or something? At the end of a day you just want to draw a custom picture of a tree, no?

Comment: Maybe SoftwareRecs.SE?

Comment: @BagiM Something with similar functionalities to that would be perferred, but the problem with those specific programs is that creating a tree that looks professional with them would require a large amount of advance planning, and I would basically have to rip up and redo the entire thing if I were to want to add or move a taxon.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks, I'll try there.

Comment: I should probably stop talking now, sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: if you're comfortable programming in R you could easily define your own phylogenetic tree in the `ape` package.  Alternatively, if you write down your tree in [Newick format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format), a standard and fairly human-friendly format, you could probably import it into any of a number of phylogenetic tools ...

Comment: @Grant I disagree. When using vector graphics program like inkscape or illustrator no advance planning would be necessary while keeping professional look. Seamlessly adding or removing taxon should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology as defined in the help center.

Comment: I think this can be a valuable question in the context of lab techniques. I've tweaked the wording of the question to highlight that this might be a valuable question for people sketching out incomplete or weird trees.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried using [Mesquite](https://www.mesquiteproject.org/)?

I used it when I taught intro bio lab course as a TA.
Basically you try to come up with yes or no questions, and based on how you answer these questions it will generate a tree similar to your second link.

Can be a little bit complicated, but I am sure there are many tutorials for it on its website.